# Reduce spark shuffle read/writes by controlling physical file/block location in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-partitioning

**Setting:**
We are receiving gzipped csv files on an hourly basis in hdfs (like 1k+ files per 24h). These files are organized in a folder structure `/data/<year>/<month>/<day>/<hour>/<unique_id>.csv.gz.`

Our etl process (spark application runs once per day. During that pipeline, we are

1. reading all files for the day,
2. applying some transformations,
3. repartition the whole dataset by hour and write the results back to hdfs (yielding 24 avro files per day).

**Observation:**
When monitoring the spark job, I can see a lot of shuffle operations (that also involve transferring a huge amount of data over the network,  especially between step 2 and 3). In step 1/2, a single task is created per file which is scheduled on the executor node that gives the best locality level (`PROCESS_LOCAL`). In step 3, we have one task per hour (24 tasks in total) each writing a single avro file back to hdfs.

The reason for these large shuffle operations is that input csv files for a specific hour are physically located at multiple different cluster nodes in hdfs. After read/transform operation, all the records for a specific hour need to be sent to a single executor which runs the write task for that hour in step 3.

**Idea for optimization:**
In order to optimize this process, the idea is to somehow physically locate all raw csv files/blocks for the same hour at the same node. We would not get rid of the shuffle operation but this would mostly require local shuffle read/writes on the executor nodes and minimize the amount of network traffic. At this point, it is also worth mentioning that network bandwidth is a very limited resource in our cluster. So, the spark application spends most of the time shuffling data around.

Is there any possibility to influence/control the physical location of a file in hdfs during the upload process or maybe by a separate script that runs on a cron schedule?

Are there any other options to optimize/streamline this process?

Comment: Putting a file on a given node might not be a problem, but what about its replicas? They will be randomly sprayed across two different nodes on a different rack if you use [default placement policy](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Replica_Placement:_The_First_Baby_Steps), so controlling subsequent Spark app to run executors where you want them will become a problem I guess.